# IOS In App Purchase: can I let the user buy again same product?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I'm trying (successfully) to follow the guidance of some IAP tutorials for IOS, e.g.:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/21081/introduction-to-in-app-purchases-in-ios-6-tutorial

My problem is: I want to let the user buy again the same product he already bought - is that possible on consumable method? (I'm searching for 2 days for an answer for it, and nothing much yet.)

The goal is to let the user buy product from hundreds of available products (hence I don't want to create hundreds of product identifiers in Itune Connect so I'm using the same product ID for all products and maintain association to real products internally (as far as Apple knows the user bought again the same product...))

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

Well, after spending few days about this issue - I've just realised this not an issue: apparently Apple don't ask for Apple ID or even password if you repurchase items soon after first purchase.

You know what that mean (actually you really know - I didn't :) ), I'll keep my iPhone away from my son after purchasing something from now on... :)

Case closed.